# Android WebView findAll not working as expected for kitkat and lollipop

Tags: android, webview

I have used webview and its work fine but i need to find some text in webview.It work upto api level 18 but after it has deprecated, so i want to know is there any way to find out this issue and solve this problem. Any body have any idea then please help me out this problem.I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but you should call loadUrl last, after everything else.
Also you seem to loop your webview with shouldOverridemethod, check my version

```
    webviewdevelopment = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewdevelopment);
    webviewdevelopment.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webviewdevelopment.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webviewdevelopment.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        Uri uri;

        try {
            uri = Uri.parse(url);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // let Android deal with this
            return true;
        }

        String host = uri.getHost(); //Host is null when user clicked on email, phone number, ...

        if (host != null && host.equals("stackoverflow.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page.  
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // You should consider this, since you are using JavaScript.. you may make your users vulnerable 
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs or anything else (email, phone number, ...)
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply but url is correct, I used "https://someurlhere.com" but i still got exception

Comment: ohkk but i have also tried like that but i got same error

Comment: i also do R & D about this but i can't able to remove this exception

Comment: ohhkk... i'll try like that and let you know if it work anyway thanks for helping me